# Abort execution of a module in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-module

I'd like to stop evaluation of a module that is being imported, without stopping the whole program.

Here's an example  of what I want to achieve:

> *main.py*
>
> ```
> print('main1')
> import testmodule
> print('main2')
> ```
>
> *testmodule.py*
>
> ```
> print(' module1')
> some_condition=True
> if some_condition:
>   exit_from_module()  # How to do this?
> print(' module2')     # This line is not executed.
> ```

Expected output:

> ```
> main1
>  module1
> main2
> ```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There is no good way to stop execution of a module.  You can raise an exception, but then your importing module will need to deal with it.  Perhaps just refactor like this:

```
print(' module1')
some_condition = True
if not some_condition:
  print(' module2')
```

Update: Even better would be to change your module to only define functions and classes, and then have the caller invoke one of those to perform the work they need done.

If you really want to do all this work during import (remember, I think it would be better not to), then you could change your module to be like this:

```
def _my_whole_freaking_module():
    print(' module1')
    some_condition = True
    if some_condition:
        return
    print(' module2')

_my_whole_freaking_module()
```

Comment: In my situation the module needs just too many exit points. Conditions won't work... I thought about these exceptions too, but I still hope for something better.

Comment: Restructure your code.  Are you sure you even want to be doing more than defining functions and classes anyway?  Importing a module and having it perform complex actions during import is a little odd.  See my edit.

Comment: I'm making a website, and I want to separate each kind of action on the website (e.g. *projects*, *blog*, *forum*) to different modules. This seemed like the best way.

Comment: @BlaXpirit: It's not the best way. You need a webframework of some kind. I assume you are using CGI now? Don't. CGI is braindead.

Comment: I just hate those frameworks. They restrict me too much and are of no help. With Python 3 I'm free to write great programs that use Unicode extensively

Comment: @BlaXpirit: You can do that with Python 2 as well. And all you'll end up doing is write your own framework anyway. The good ones will not restrict you. Check out Pyramid, for example.

Comment: @BlaXpirit: I'm not sure what you mean by frameworks restricting you, but that's probably beyond the scope of this thread.  What I don't understand is how exiting early from a module is helping you structure your web code?  Why do you need to exit early?

Comment: You should raise an exception and let the importing code deal with it. Raising is the one and only right way to go here.

Answer (score 6):

My main.py looks like this,

```
print 'main 1'

try:
    import my_module
except ImportError:
    pass

print 'main 2'
```

and my_module.py looks like this,

```
print 'module 1'

if True:
    raise ImportError
else:
    pass

print 'module 2'
```

output is,

```
main 1
module 1
main 2
```

Comment: This is the only correct python solution to the problem.  Thanks!

Comment: This idea looks very elegant... but unfortunately in such case the main program does not get any input from the called module. It acts as if the module has not been called at all. But I would like to keep the definitions from the module read before the exception has been raised. Is there a way?

Answer (score 2):

You can wrap the module code inside function, like this:

```
def main():
  print(' module1')
  some_condition=True
  if some_condition:
    return
  print(' module2')

main()
```

Comment: Another problem is all the variables in main have to be declared as global to make it work same as before.